How to disable the bottom bar on Samsung Galaxy Tab S9?
I am fond of using gestures instead of navigation buttons, because it gives me 100% of the screen for content. I have it turned on on my phone and until now had as well on my tablet.
After the latest update, my Samsung Galaxy Tab S9 returned to showing regular navigation buttons. I have turned them off, but there is a horizontal bar on the bottom of the screen, which I failed to turn off. Is there some hidden setting, which allows disabling it?
Edit: Thedrag  navigation seems to be really problematic after the update - I barely can open application switcher. This is really a bad experience :(



AFAIK, the bottom horizontal bar is a standard UI to indicate gesture navigation (it's there on my Samsung Galaxy M12 and Google Pixel 3a). I've never seen a built-in feature to disable it altogether. You might want to try the following trick using immersive mode, which I know it worked for navigation bar, but not sure for gesture bar: Oreo/Pixel2: Bottom Navigation Bar is no longer fading out

@AndrewT. All: Samsung Galaxy S9+, Samsung Galaxy S23 Ultra, Samsung Galaxy Tab S8 and Samsung Galaxy Tab S9 (until the latest update) allowed to remove the navigation bar completely.
